# ASP Identity Roles not appearing in Client using IdentityServer v3

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3

Feel like I'm missing something in the IdentityServer or client configuration.  I've upgraded from ASP membership to Identity, then have switched out to using SSO with IdentityServer.  I can login via Identity Server and am returned to the client app where I can debug and see the UserKey and claims, but I can't see any roles in the claims and user.IsInRole(roleName) always returns false.

The IdentityServer configuration:

```
public class Scopes
{
    public static IEnumerable<Scope> Get()
    {
        return new Scope[]
        {
            StandardScopes.OpenId,
            StandardScopes.Profile,
            StandardScopes.Email,
            StandardScopes.AllClaims,
            StandardScopes.Roles,
            StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
            new Scope
            {
                IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true,
                Name = "read",
                DisplayName = "Read data",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                Emphasize = false,
            },
            new Scope
            {
                Name = "write",
                DisplayName = "Write data",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                Emphasize = false, //true
            },
            new Scope
            {
                Name = "forbidden",
                DisplayName = "Forbidden scope",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                Emphasize = false //true
            }
         };
    }
}



public static class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new[]
    {
        new Client
        {
            Enabled = true,
            ClientName = "MVC Client",
            ClientId = "implicitclient",
            Flow = Flows.Implicit,
             AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
                Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Email,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Roles
            },

            RedirectUris = new List<string>
            {
                "https://localhost:44301/"
            }
        },
        new Client
        {
            Enabled = true,
            ClientName = "MyClientName",
            ClientId = "myclientName",
            Flow = Flows.Implicit,
             AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
                Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Email,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Roles,
                "read",
                "write"
            },
            RedirectUris = new List<string>
            {
                "https://localhost:44302/"
            }
        }
    };
    }
}


public static IdentityServerServiceFactory Configure()
    {
        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();

        var scopeStore = new InMemoryScopeStore(Scopes.Get());
        factory.ScopeStore = new Registration<IScopeStore>(scopeStore);
        var clientStore = new InMemoryClientStore(Clients.Get());
        factory.ClientStore = new Registration<IClientStore>(clientStore);

        factory.CorsPolicyService = new Registration<ICorsPolicyService>(new DefaultCorsPolicyService { AllowAll = true });

        return factory;
    }
```

The Client configuration (MVC 5 app):

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "myclientname",
            Authority = "https://localhost:44300/core", //Constants.BaseAddress,  //STS Server Address
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44302/", //This site
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            //Scope = "openid email write",
            Scope = "openid email roles",

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                {
                    var token = n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken;

                    // persist access token in cookie
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                    {
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(
                            new Claim("access_token", token));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Use a CustomUserService?

Comment: Thanks, are there any links to the wiki/documentation that explain this further.  I've seen you can add a CustomUserService but I'm not clear on how that solves the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomUserService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope roles has only one scope claim, "**role**", this scope claim has the following property "**AlwaysIncludeinIdToken**" set to false, this means if you ask for the "**token**" *response_type* it won't be sent implicitly. (This is my understanding, maybe is not that simple)

First try to remove the "**token**" *response_type*, and ask only for the "**openid**" and "**roles**" scope. If this solves the problem, then it is not sending them implicitly.

You need to ask for the remaining claims, i.e. those not sent in the "id_**token**" request, explicitly. You need to use the *access_token* you got and the "**userinfo**" endpoint. (As a tip search in the documentation for the correct use of the endpoints)

**EDIT**:[UserInfo Documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/userinfo.html), this maybe usefull on how to call the **Userinfo** endpoint.